# Groovy SQL DataSource Connection handling, withTransaction

Tags: grails, groovy, connection, datasource

I've been quite confused at groovy SQL documentation as far as the connection handling is concerned. I need to understand the best practices or how to actually handle the underlying connection properly.

Let's say I have an object like this.

```
SqL sql = new Sql(dataSource);
sql.withTransaction {
 .....
}
```

Now should I close connection? `sql.close` in a finally block? Or I just leave it there.

Now consider this:

```
SqL sql = Sql.newInstance (connection parameters);
sql.withTransaction {...}
```

Is `sql.close()` required now?

Now here is another variant.

```
Sql sql //(with any constructor).
Sql.//[do something] without a withTransaciton ...
```

Do I have to manage the connection myself this time? Or I can still leave it there without `sql.close()`.

In any of the above case I'm writing my code in a Grails service which may or may not be transactional.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

afaik, all methods do the connection handling themselves.
you should deal with it only if you used the constructor that receives a connection.
if you don't need transacions and you want to reuse the connection you colud use `Sql#cacheConnection(Closure)`

Comment: reuse connection? Can you please throw some more light on this?

Comment: when you do not use a withTransaction block a connection is requested from the data source and closed afterwards.  
when you do use it, the connection is returned only afther the block ends.  
what the cacheConnection does is prevent emulate this without the automatic commit, so you can perform several queries/inserts with the same connection, perhaps doing some commits/rollbacks manually in the middle.  
the code of the groovy.sql.Sql class is actually quite clean, i think one can learn a few tricks looking at it

Comment: Yup, I got it now. Also went through the groovy source code. Seems logical, after all Groovy SQL is a wrapper over JDBC so what it does is to help us to use minimum boiler plate code e.g. close connections explicitly. Thanks.

Comment: This is/was also helpful in an Oracle CLOB context where you have to make sure that you "create" the CLOB with the same connection that will later use it in an execute call.